# binding datagrid to combobox WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Please help me !
In SQL server ,i create  table temp:

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
user_temp nvarchar(5),
year_temp int)
```

the Value in table temp:

```
user_temp        year_temp
   A                5
   B                6
   C                5
```

In  window, i create one Datagrid and one ComboBox, i wrote:

```
Private Sub Windowtemp_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim s as string="select * from temp"
    Dim cmd as new New SqlClient.SqlCommand(s, connect)
    Dim adaptertemp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    adaptertemp.SelectCommand = cmd

    Dim tabletemp As New DataTable

    adaptertemp.Fill(tabletemp)
    datagridtemp.ItemsSource = tabletemp.DefaultView
    cmd.Dispose()
    adaptertemp.Dispose()
    tabletemp.Dispose()

    Dim i as interger

    for i= 10 to 20
        cbo.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

in datagrid selection_changed:

```
Private Sub gridtemp_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangeEventArgs) Handles gridtemp.SelectionChanged
    cbo.Text = gridtemp.SelectedItem.row(1).ToString
End Sub
```

But the Combobox not show value of gridtemp. What should I suppose to do to make this right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your post.  Please clarify the correlation of why the grid changes the combobox.  Also, why is your combobox only set with values from 10 to 20, yet your data values representing years is only 5 & 6.  Without more clarification, you might not get a definitive solution.  Again, edit your existing post, don't just add to comments.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedItem` returns a `DataRowView`. Try this:

```
Private Sub gridtemp_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles gridtemp.SelectionChanged
    If Not gridtemp.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Dim selectedItem = CType(gridtemp.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
        cbo.SelectedItem = Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I mean the user can change any value in the ComboBox because the ComboBox I set the property IsEditable is True. I bind the Textbox ok, but the ComboBox I do not know how to bind.

Comment: Please explain what you want to be able to to with the ComboBox. You are adding integers from 10 to 20 it, aren't you?